# Do I need SQL_NO_CACHE for write intensive query?

Tags: mysql, performance

When I establish a connection to DB, I have to write about 30,000 records with an INSERT statement. I've read in a book that I should do it !

Questions

- Do I need to do SQL_NO_CACHE ?
- Is it gonna increase performance and insert rate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@randy is correct in his assertion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16568/877) because I learned from Baron Schwartz awhile ago that caching buffers for queries (query cache) and caching for data and indexes (MyISAM Key Buffer [indexes only], InnoDB Buffer Pool [data and indexes)]) are orthogonal. In other words, one has nothing to do with, and has no bearing on, the other. @randy gets +1 for this.

If you are doing bulk INSERTS, I would like to make two suggestions:

### SUGGESTION #1 : Use extended INSERTs

If you have 30,000 INSERT to make, please do not do 30,000 INSERTs. Try to bunch up 500-1000 rows at a time. This is what mysqldump does when creating a dump file so that when a table is being reloaded, it has hundreds or thousands of rows being inserted.

So, instead of

```
INSERT INTO tblname VALUES (...);
INSERT INTO tblname VALUES (...);
.
.
.
INSERT INTO tblname VALUES (...);
```

Try to group them like this

```
INSERT INTO tblname VALUES (...),(...),(...),(...),(...);
INSERT INTO tblname VALUES (...),(...),(...),(...),(...);
.
.
.
INSERT INTO tblname VALUES (...),(...),(...),(...),(...);
```

The more you group together, the better it will be for the next suggestion...

### SUGGESTION #2 : Use a bigger bulk insert buffer

Most people forget to [set the bulk insert buffer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_bulk_insert_buffer_size). The default is 8M. You can really improve performance for extended INSERTs by increasing it to something like

```
[mysqld]
bulk_insert_buffer_size=512M
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: +1 for the first paragraph, and marked as an answer for your very helpful suggestions. I appreciate it.

Comment: Does myISAM or InnoDB matter for setting this option?

Comment: Is setting `UNIQUE_CHECKS=0` and `foreign_key_checks=0` help on increasing performance? what is its drawbacks? (All of my DB tables are InnoDB)

Comment: And finally one part of my project is to bulk insert, if I set bulk_insert_buffer_size in mysql.cnf does it affect other normal inserts(1-10 QPS)? **I use transaction**

Answer (score 2):

No.

SQL_NO_CACHE is only relevant for SELECT statements. It is not an option for INSERT or LOAD DATA statements. "[The SQL_CACHE and SQL_NO_CACHE options affect caching of query results in the query cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)"

Moreover, the [query cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-cache-operation.html) itself has to be enabled, then is invalidated when the underlying dataset has changed.

If you're performing a series of SELECT statements at the same time as the bulk load, then you will save a few microseconds by using SQL_NO_CACHE, but it is only an option as part of the SELECT.